# Extract matching expressions from a SET data type

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to work on a SET data type and find all matching patterns.
I have a working code:

```
d=SET type input
fin_list=[]
for i in d:
    mat = re.findall(r"\w+\.\w+",str(i))
    if mat:
        fin_list.append(' '.join(mat))

print ','.join(fin_list)
```

e.g:

```
Input:
 set(['databasename.tablename', 'hello', 'fact.table'])
Output:
 databasename.tablename,fact.table
```

Please suggest an efficient and pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Your current way is good , why need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach using `str.join`.

**Demo:**

```
import re
d = set(['databasename.tablename', 'hello', 'fact.table'])
print( ", ".join(re.findall(r"\w+\.\w+", "|".join(d))) )
```

**Output:**

```
databasename.tablename, fact.table
```

Answer (score 0):

I would compile the regex pattern only once, and use a list_comprehension:

```
import re

s = set(['databasename.tablename', 'hello', 'fact.table'])
rx = re.compile(r"\w+\.\w+")
fin_list = [" ".join(rx.findall(i)) for i in s if rx.search(i)]

print fin_list
```

gives as expected:

```
['databasename.tablename', 'fact.table']
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure why you are using join in append.

a simple one liner would do the job for you.

```
d=SET type input
output = [element for element in d if "." in element] # this line if you want all the elements of set having '.' inside.
Time taken : 0:00:00.005000
output = [element for element in d if "." in element and element.count(".") == 1] # this if you want 1 '.' inside
Time taken: 0:00:00.007000
output = [element for element in d if "." in element and element.count(".") == 1 and not element.startswith(".")] # this if you dont want elements starting with '.'
print(",".join(output))
Time taken: 0:00:00.007000

Your code: 0:00:00.012000
```

Comment: I'm a beginner in python. I was trying to avoid the type errors.